# Help building patched android framework

Tags: android, build, platform, cyanogenmod, bootclasspath

I am new to Android platform development. I have just succeded building [Cyanogenmod 7](http://www.cyanogenmod.com/) sources after applying a patch, which adds extra jars to the system (fit into /system/framework directory).

After flashing the device and checking that the new custom jars are there, and decompiling (extracting classes.dex and running [dex2jar](http://code.google.com/p/dex2jar/)) just to verify that the needed classes are there, I see my test program crashing due to ClassNotFound exceptions.

Since the compiled custom java sources seem ok, have I missed something in the building process so my applications can use these new framework classes?

**UPDATE**:

I realized that framework jars are included inside an environment variable called BOOTCLASSPATH, which is defined in *init.rc*. I modified it to include the new jars from SEEK project (*smartcardapi.jar* and *org.simalliance.openmobileapi.jar*). I rebuilt the image and flashed my phone.

The device now does not start. I have read [something here](http://osdir.com/ml/android-porting/2010-02/msg00312.html) about class optimizations that are run against BOOTCLASSPATH classes. The advice is not to mess with BOOTCLASSPATH.

But what can I do so my applications can use the extended API classes defined in the new jars?